# How to launch python script on pi zero without a keyboard or OS

Tags: raspberry-pi-zero

I'm Making a raspberry pi zero handheld for games like pong and I don't have the adapter or keyboard for it I also don't have that weird desktop thing I see people using I'm running it on pi OS full and this is my first time doing anything like this how would I get it to launch?

The only thing I've seen about this uses the desktop and the key board is there a way I could edit the micro SD card?

Comment: You’ll have to connect standard input devices (e.g. keyboard) that you can use until you create a startup procedure to load into a program that doesn’t need them on subsequent power cycles. Please see [ask].